# VueBankCard component is not displayed

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have tried to place component of bank card ([avto-dev/bank-card-vue-component](https://github.com/avto-dev/bank-card-vue-component)) in my frontend application on Vue.js, but I can't find this component in my frame after I followed their instructions on Github.

Here you can see my `package.json` file:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@avto-dev/bank-card-vue-component": "^1.3.0",
  ...
  ...
},
```

`main.js`:

```js
import VueBankCard from "@avto-dev/bank-card-vue-component"
import "@avto-dev/bank-card-vue-component/dist/bank-card-vue-component.css"

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(PrimeVue).use(router)

...
...

app.component('VueBankCard', VueBankCard)
```

and `Profile.vue` where I use this component:

```
<template>
<div class="profile">
  <div class="bank-card-block">
    <Card class="custom-card bank-card">
      <template>
        <VueBankCard
            is-small
            is-new
        ></VueBankCard>
      </template>
    </Card>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Profile",
  data(){
    return{
      valueFields: {
        cardName: "",
        cardNumber: "",
        cardMonth: "",
        cardYear: "",
        cardCvv: "",
      },
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.profile{
  display: flex;
  width: 94%;
}

.bank-card-block{
  width: 45%;
}

.bank-card{
  border-radius: 15px;
}

</style>
```

I have no hypothesis where it can be mistake.

Can you explain me what I have skipped, because all what I have done was only according to instructions in the github of this component.

Comment: If there are no warnings or errors in the console (both browser's and terminal) - then you are doing it right and the problem could be the component itself. Perhaps it does not render anything if you don't feed it properly with data in its props?

Comment: the syntax of your `main.js` tells me you're using vue 3, but the documentation for this custom component only lists compatibility with vue 2...  you most likely can't use this component unless you downgrade